# Error consulta SQL - Keys -

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola a todos me sale el siguiente error:

> "EntradaVTP_SolicitudSalida1". The conflict occurred in database
>   "PME", table "dbo.EntradaVTP", column 'SolicitudSalidaId'.

La tabla EntradaVTP tiene los siguientes datos: `ID, VTPID, SolicitudSalidaId, Anula`

y tengo esta info:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo borrar esta información sin tener errores?

Salida VTP tiene los siguientes campos: `ID, VTPID, REABASTECIDAID` ....

Mi código actual es el siguiente:

```
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME; 
SET @DATE = '2016/12/31 23:59:59';
-- Guardamos en una tabla la ID todas las SolicitudesVTP que son del rango de fechas. Para eliminarlas de Entradas y Salidas VTP
DECLARE @tablaVTPID TABLE (id int) 
INSERT INTO @tablaVTPID (id) 
SELECT SolicitudVTP.Id from SolicitudVTP 
WHERE SolicitudVTP.FechaEntrega >@DATE or SolicitudVTP.FechaEntrega is null

DELETE FROM dbo.EntradaVTP 
WHERE EntradaVTP.id IN (
   SELECT Solicitud.id 
   FROM dbo.Solicitud 
   WHERE Solicitud.FechaCreacion > @DATE
);

DELETE FROM dbo.SalidaVTP  
WHERE SalidaVTP.id IN  (
   SELECT Solicitud.id 
   FROM dbo.Solicitud 
   WHERE Solicitud.FechaCreacion > @DATE
);  

DELETE FROM dbo.EntradaVTP 
WHERE VTPId in (SELECT id FROM @tablaVTPID)   

DELETE FROM dbo.SalidaVTP 
WHERE ReabastecidaId in (SELECT id FROM @tablaVTPID)

Delete from SalidaVTP 
Where SalidaVTP.ReabastecidaId in (
   SELECT SolicitudVTP.Id 
   FROM dbo.SolicitudVTP 
   Where SolicitudVTP.FechaEntrega >@DATE
);
```

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con este código.

```
CREATE proc [App].[spBorrado](
@ID int
) as
declare  
 @SQLScriptSelect nvarchar(max)
,@SQLScriptDelete nvarchar(max;

if object_id('tempdb..#tempFksID') is not null drop table #tempFksID;

select 
    cast(f.name as varchar(255)) as foreign_key_name
    , cast(c.name as varchar(255)) as foreign_table
    , cast(fc.name as varchar(255)) as foreign_column
    , cast(p.name as varchar(255)) as parent_table
    , cast(rc.name as varchar(255)) as parent_column
    , SQLSriptDelete = N'delete from '+SCHEMA_NAME(c.schema_id)+'.'+cast(c.name as varchar(255))+' where ID = '+CAST(@ID as varchar(100))
    , SQLSriptSelect = N'select * from '+SCHEMA_NAME(c.schema_id)+'.'+cast(c.name as varchar(255))+' where ID = '+CAST(@ID as varchar(100))
INTO #tempFksID
from  sysobjects f
inner join sys.objects c on f.parent_obj = c.object_id
inner join sysreferences r on f.id = r.constid
inner join sysobjects p on r.rkeyid = p.id
inner join syscolumns rc on r.rkeyid = rc.id and r.rkey1 = rc.colid
inner join syscolumns fc on r.fkeyid = fc.id and r.fkey1 = fc.colid
where f.type = 'F' and fc.name = 'ID' and p.name = 'EntradaVTP'

SELECT @SQLScriptDelete = STUFF((
        SELECT CHAR(10) + SQLSriptDelete
        FROM #tempFksID
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 1, '')
FROM #tempFksID

SELECT @SQLScriptSelect = STUFF((
        SELECT CHAR(10) +SQLSriptSelect
        FROM #tempFksID
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 1, '')
FROM #tempFksID

--  execute(@SQLScriptSelect)   
execute(@SQLScriptDelete)

delete from dbo.EntradaVTP where ID = @ID
```

Comment: Te puedo preguntar que hace este código? Me cuesta entenderlo.

Comment: Claro, lo que hace es buscar todas las tablas que hace referencia al Primary key(campo) de la tabla que indicas en el Select.

Luego, genera los scripts para borrar esos registros que apuntan al Primary key en cuestión, y finalmente elimina el registro principal.

Comment: Si podrias compartir el diagrama entidad relacion de la base de datos tendriamos mas visibilidad para identificar el problema